# Reset Uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I have one form with uploadify as one of the component.
I am submitting my entire form via Ajax. But problem is that, I want to reset uploadify component after ajax response comes.

Please tell me if you know any way to reset that component entirely.

Thanks for your help.

Hussain

Comment: does reset mean to clear the queue ?

Comment: Hussain, This is very old ques though, did you got any solution for this? Because I am also facing same problem. If you got any, please share here. That will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly be "reset the form", can't you do something like this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'something.php',
    // other params
    success: function(response) {
        $('#fileUpload').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : '../js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : '../js/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : '../js/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : '../uploads',
        'auto'      : true
                    // bla bla bla
    });
    }
}
```

You pratically re-uploadify the form on the onSuccess callback of the AJAX call. Posting your JS/HTML and exaplaining what you exactly mean by "reset" will get you better answers, I think.

Comment: I have already initialized Uploadify when page is loaded, now user submits the data via ajax. once ajax all is successfull, I want to reinitialize/reset uploadify completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify('destroy')
```

Calling destory will reset the uploadify back to it's original state.

More info about destroy is [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/destroy/)

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

we need to just remove the title i.e. name of the uploaded file from uploadify controller.

for example, in my page I have `span` which holds the name of file. So at the time of uplodify initialization it will be like this

```
<label id="lbl">No file selected</label>
```

after uploading file this will be converted to

```
<label id="lbl">img1.png</label>
```

Now after the ajax call we can just remove the text from the span and the uploadify is reset ed back.

```
$("#lbl").html('No file selected');
```

I have used this when I am deleting the uploaded image. And it worked for me. Hope it helps others.